# IFileOperation::RenameItem でディレクトリを統合するときにファイルが衝突するとエラーになる

Tags: windows-10, winapi

Win32Api の IFileOperation::RenameItem() を使用してディレクトリ名をすでに存在するディレクトリと同じ名前に変更し、ディレクトリを統合しようとしています。

実行して最初のダイアログで

> この宛先には既に '(既存フォルダ名)' フォルダーが存在します。
> 同じ名前のファイルがある場合、それらのファイルを上書きするかどうかたずねられます。
> 2024/01/22 12:00 で作成したフォルダーを以下のフォルダーと統合しますか？

といったダイアログが表示され、一見うまくいっているように思えたのですが、同じ名前のファイルが存在する場合、[はい]を選択後、

> エラー 0x80070057: パラメーターが間違っています。

のエラーダイアログが表示され、処理に失敗します。

正しく処理を完了させるためにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

---

以下C#で実装したコードの一部です。

```
using (ComReleaser<IShellItem> sourceItem = CreateShellItem(src))
{
    var fo = (IFileOperation)new FileOperation();
    fo.RenameItem(sourceItem.Item, dstName, null);
    fo.PerformOperations();
}
```

環境は Windows10 64bit です。

ちなみに、 SHFileOperation を使用した名前変更でも同じエラーが発生します。

Comment: こちらのAPI [MoveAsync(IStorageFolder, String, NameCollisionOption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.moveasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-storage-storagefile-moveasync(windows-storage-istoragefolder-system-string-windows-storage-namecollisionoption))を使って [NameCollisionOption 列挙型](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/uwp/api/windows.storage.namecollisionoption?view=winrt-22621) に ReplaceExisting を指定するとか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 教えていただいたメソッドは WindowsRuntime のものであり Win32Api とは種類が異なります。かつ、そのメソッドはファイルをフォルダーに移動させるためのもののようで、用途も異なります。

Comment: UWPのAPIは.NETアプリから呼び出せますよ。[超簡単！ WPFなどの.NETのアプリからUWPのAPIを使う～日本語の読み仮名を取得するAPIを題材に](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/10654), [WPFアプリ（.Net Framework）でUWPのAPIを使う](https://qiita.com/FumiyaHr/items/13de3dcbd9b81d9d27f0) ただ用途が違うと言うのはそうでしょうね。[StorageFolder クラス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder?view=winrt-22621) `現在、"MoveAsync" または同様のメソッドはありません。` あと質問についてはこんなAPIを呼び出す必要もありそうですが。[IFileOperation::GetAnyOperationsAborted メソッド (shobjidl_core.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-getanyoperationsaborted)

Comment: GetAnyOperationsAborted() を最後に呼んでみましたが、挙動に変化はありませんでした。

Comment: まあ情報を取ってくるだけのAPIなので動作には変化無いでしょうね。元々の処理で事前のモード設定や呼び出す処理への問題発生時パラメータ等が無いということは、その動作が仕様なのでは？ Microsoftの開発者フォーラムで訊ねてみるか、問題の現象が発生したらファイルを1個1個移動するような別の処理に切り替えるといった対処になるのかもしれません。